# .net maui hide separator in title

Tags: maui

I have a .net MAUI application where I try to hide the separator on iOS in between the content and the navigation bar of the default navigation page.

[image]

I have this code on iOS for that which I call in the `OnAppearing`:

```
On<iOS>().SetHideNavigationBarSeparator(true);
```

That work when I start the app from scratch. But when I send it into the background and resume it after a while, the separator is shown again.
Does anyone know how I can hide this permanently?

EDIT: I found out that it has to do with adding a ThemedChangedHandler that would update the bar color. I have this in my navigation page:

```
public DefaultNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root)
{
    SetBarColors();
    On<iOS>().SetHideNavigationBarSeparator(true);
    Application.Current!.RequestedThemeChanged += (_, _) => { SetBarColors(); };
}

private void SetBarColors()
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Application.Current?.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark
        ? (Color)App.ResourceDictionary["Colors"]["BackgroundColorDark"]
        : (Color)App.ResourceDictionary["Colors"]["BackgroundColorLight"];

    BarTextColor = Application.Current?.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark
        ? (Color)App.ResourceDictionary["Colors"]["TextPrimaryColorDark"]
        : (Color)App.ResourceDictionary["Colors"]["TextPrimaryColorLight"];
}
```

When I remove this line it works as expected:

```
Application.Current!.RequestedThemeChanged += (_, _) => { SetBarColors(); };
```

Although I don't understand why. I tried adding the code to hide the separator in the "SetBarColors" method aswell, without any success.

Repro sample can be found here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ang3D30bKDOhs7I9_wi3i2-4diRW4w?e=GXevd6

Comment: Have you tried to set it in XAML like `xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"`  `ios:NavigationPage.HideNavigationBarSeparator="True"`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a xaml page (or I don't see where it would be). I create NavigationPage directly when assigning the mainpage.

Comment: 1. Do you mean you are creating it like `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`? 2. Can you help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce this issue?

Comment: 1. Exactly
2. the project itself is open source: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox
I can see if I can create a smaller repo in the coming days.

Comment: Have you tried doing this in the Constructor maybe?

Comment: @NPadrutt Thanks for your response, there's compile error of the project you provided, consider provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would be much appreciated!

Comment: @FreakyAli That was, where I had it originally but with the same result -> fine on a normal startup but with the separator present after hibernation of the app.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I updated my original post with what I found out, an a link to a reproduction example.

Comment: @NPadrutt Thanks for the update, I'll see if there's a solution to fix it.